# Accessing DOM element in Angular 2 and change the element's class attribute

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I'm new in angular2. my code is like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'main',
   template: `
    <div class="current">
    </div>
  `
})

export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
   ngOnInit(): void {
     //change the div class from current to next...
   }
}
```

i'd like to change the div class from 'current' to 'next'.

i appropriate if you let me know what is the best way do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars).

In the example below, the reference variable `#target` is added to the desired element and then the [decorator `@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html) (`@ViewChild('target') target`) allows you to access the variable in your component.

From there, you can get a reference to the DOM element by accessing the [`nativeElement` property](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html) on the variable.

Here is an example where the class name is updated:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'main',
  template: `
  <div #target class="current">
  </div>
  `
})
export class MainComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('target') target;

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let element = this.target.nativeElement;

    element.className = 'next';
  }
}
```

However, it's worth pointing out that you can handle most DOM manipulation with the build-in DOM directives. In this case you could just use the [`ngClass` directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html) to bind a variable with the class attribute:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'main',
  template: `
  <div [ngClass]="targetClass">
  </div>
  `
})
export class MainComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  private targetClass: string = 'current';

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.targetClass = 'next';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josh for you quick response. it's working beautifully.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you suggested `@ViewChild('target') target;` instead of the explicitly typed `@ViewChild('target') target: QueryList<ElementRef>;`?

Comment: you could also use @HostBinding('class') private targetClass to handle the class change.